# Why does same image in two ArcGIS ArcMap configurations show different extent numbers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, aster

I would like to get hear from you about the situation I am seeing here. What It got my eye was that when I download an ASTER from Reverb/ Echo from USGS website.
At work, I load my ASTER file to my ArcMap and the ASTER shows the extent is in decimal degrees and the spatial reference shows the UTM Zone 13 Northern Hemisphere.So, I was not able to overlay with my known Projected Coordinate System in NAD 1983 UTM 13 Zone to overlay each other. I have been having some projection issues because I want it to reprojection to NAD 1983 UTM Zone 13N.

Now I backup the file and took it home and load it to my home ArcMap and it shows the extent is in meters and the spatial reference shows UTM Zone 13 Northern Hemisphere.
I am wondering if this has to do with ArcGIS 10.1 at work was not installed properly or did I did do something that cause the different coordinate system on my ArcGIS at work?
I would like to find the solution because I know someone else had the same situation I am in.

I revised the error from home to work

Comment: Do both installations have the same patches/service packs? Also, I wonder if you may have 'lost' a related .aux or other file that contained the bad coordinate system info when you backed up the file.

Comment: In the **Catalog** window have you used **Properties** from your image at both work and home to examine these numbers?  If they are identical there, then use the edit button to record this important detail in your question, because I think that will narrow your question to the coordinate system of your data frame in the two configurations you are using.

Comment: mkenndy, My ArcGIS 10.1 shows SP1 for Desktop and Builid is 3143.

Answer (score 1):

When you open an image in ArcMap, that image will be displayed using the coordinate system of the dataframe. So, there is an on-the-fly reprojection. 
Now, it seems that the coordinate system of the dataframe in your office computer is different from the one one of your home computer. 
To solve this, before opening any image in ArcMap, you should go to the dataframe properties and set the coordinate system to none. If you succesfully do that, your image will be displayed using the its own coordinate system and not that of the dataframe.

Comment: That is what I did and still have the same problem, I believe it is the software that reads differently.