# Extent and Projection on ASTER issue on my ArcGIS 10.1 ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, aster

On my previous post on my ASTER issue, [ASTER extent or projection issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72533/why-does-same-image-in-two-arcgis-arcmap-configurations-show-different-extent-nu). I decided to revisit on this issue. I am still puzzled as to why my ASTER has geographic coordinate system on its extent but the Spatial Reference tells me it is in UTM Zone 13 Northern Hemishphere and the datum shows me the Datum Not specified based on GRS 1980 spheriod. This is done in my office. The ASTER I download came from this website: [USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)

Now, I have ArcMap 10.1 at home and the extent and the projection shows me they are in the correct extent UTM numbers and correct projection.

How can one ArcMap 10.1 in my office and ArcMap 10.1 at home showed me two different extent numbers: One in geographic coordinate system and Projection UTM numbers ??

What could have cause them to show different extent numbers and why ? Could it be the installed change something within the ArcGIS program ?

For your information: My ERDAS 2011 show me the ASTER is in UTM meters and UTM Zone 13 projection and were able to overlay with polygons.

I will see if I can uninstall and reinstall my ArcGIS to see if it is the same results.

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Is the raster format HDF-EOS or GeoTIFF or something else? If it's GeoTIFF, it would be interesting to see the header information on both copies using something like [listgeo](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/).

Comment: mkennedy - The USGS EarthExplorer has three download options to choose from: Standard, Full Resolution Browse Product and GIS Ready Bundle. I choose the Standard Format and that one came with .hdf file. So, when you bring it to ArcMap, the next thing it brings up Subdataset Selection. It holds a lot of subdatasets within the hdf file. FYI, to access these ASTER from USGS EarthExplorer is free of charge and I suggest you to give a try and see if it came the same result as mine. They do have their jpeg that has georeferenced but you dont know which bands they put in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBERT and I did some discussion off-line and I downloaded a different ASTER L1B scene which is in HDF4 format. Just as the OP saw, the coordinate reference system was interpreted by ArcGIS as UTM zone 12 North on a non-specific GCS. However, the raster extents are in decimal degrees. We've decided this is a bug in ArcGIS and it's going to be submitted. It's reproducible in a development version of 10.2.1 as well.

Solution/workaround: Use the Define Projection Tool to change the coordinate system to WGS84 or NAD83.

Comment: Thank you very much and I am sure others will be delighted to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested previously, it sounds like the dataframe does not match the image.

Try this: Start a new, empty ArcMap project. First, make sure the dataframe coordinate system is set to none in dataframe properties. Next, add the polygons that you want to overlay, and confirm that these are displaying as expected in the right coordinate system. Finally, add the Aster image.

Comment: I'm familiar with that but still doesn't work. It could be the wrong projection.

Comment: What could be the wrong projection? Please be more specific

Comment: The extent shows in geographic coordinates but the projection is in UTM 13 Zone Northern hemisphere so it would not overlay with the polgyon (it has known projected coordinate) I already provide the picture above.

Comment: So from this it sounds like the view extent is defaulting to geographic coordinates even for a polygon dataset defined as UTM Zone 13?

Comment: That is correct, congrene. Ever work with ASTER in the past ?